# Как добавить фоновую музыку на сайт HTML5

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, аудио

Я пытался добавлять музыку на свой сайт но у меня возникала такая проблема то что Музыка останавливалась после обновления страницы и только через час я мог воспроизвести ее заново после обновления страницы также у меня возникли проблемы с громкостью музыки она максимальная по умолчанию какие бы я не пробовал скрипты она по умолчанию максимальная

Кто нибудь подкиньте скрипт пожалуйста

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Музыка в фоновом режиме

Comment: Ну хотя-бы код покажи... Не гадать же, как и что там у тя реализовано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<audio src="/music/good_enough.mp3">
<p>Если вы видите это, ваш браузер не поддерживает тег audio.</p>
</audio>
```

Если же вам нужны элементы управления:

```
<audio src="/music/good_enough.mp3" controls>
<p>Если вы видите это, ваш браузер не поддерживает тег audio.</p>
</audio>
```

Ещё можно использовать `<embed>`:

```
<embed src="/music/good_enough.mp3" width="180" height="90" loop="false" autostart="false" hidden="true" />
```

---

*Данный ответ является переводом [ответа участника topcat3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402388/2553424) на вопрос «[Play sound file in a web-page in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13402336/2553424)».*

Comment: Хоть переводы вопросов и ответов с английского SO и не возбраняются, их надо делать с передачей смысла, а не в виде словесной каши машинного перевода. Исправил текст и добавил ссылку на оригинал, [как того требует лицензия сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4975/208074).

Comment: Наверное стоит еще отметить, что автовоспроизведение в chrome может не работать из-за новых политик.

Comment: Э, Парни, ну если человек сам найти не может...

Comment: Да спасибо все понял буду знать